# Returning a 424 error with no cause

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a 424 error on a piece of VBA I am cleaning up. I didn't write all of this, but there doesn't seem to be any reason for this error to come up. Its excel for mac so of course it won't toggle the breakpoint for me 
: (
Any ideas would be very helpful

```
Sub Transform()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Long
Dim fndList, rpcList, endlist As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

fndList = Array("1","2","3")
endlist = Array("x","y","z")
rpcList = Array("a","b","c")

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ws

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows(1).Delete
Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete

.Range("A1:P1") = endlist
.Range("A2:P2") = rpcList



For Each c In .Range("A4:A" & LastRow)
   ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="https://" & cell.Value
Next c


For Each c In .Range("B4:B" & LastRow)
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"
Next c


For Each c In .Range("C4:C" & LastRow)
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"
Next c


For Each c In .Range("G4:G" & LastRow)
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="https://tool" & cell.Value
Next c

Dim l As Integer
Dim larray(1 To 10) As Integer
Dim k As Integer
k = 1

For l = 3 To 600
If Cells(l, 2).Value > Cells(l, 3).Value Then
    Cells(l, 2).ClearContents
    Cells(l, 3).ClearContents

End If
Next l

Dim h As Integer
h = 1

Dim m As Integer
For m = 3 To 600
If Cells(m, 2) > Now() Then
   Cells(m, 2).ClearContents
   End If

If Cells(m, 3) > Now() Then
   Cells(m, 3).ClearContents
   End If
Next m

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You have `With ws` but the following `Rows()` have no leading period, so by default they will refer to the ActiveSheet

Answer (score 3):

Your `For Each` control is `c` but you are using `cell` as the hyperlink parameter.  Change `c` to `cell`.

> ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="https://" & cell.Value

```
    For Each cell In .Range("A4:A" & LastRow)
        cell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell , Address:="https://" & cell.Value
    Next cell

    .Range("B4:C" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"

    For Each cell In .Range("G4:G" & LastRow)
        cell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="https://tool" & cell.Value
    Next cell
```

Comment: But you can't add multiple hyperlinks to the same cell?  I'ts not clear what the OP is looking to do here.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. I forgot about that because I stopped adding the control after `Next` when I was writing vbscripts.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks again!!  Sorry about the sloppy work.

Comment: I just tested and actually it does seem to work even with Activecell - that is over-ridden by the `anchor` argument.  Still - it looks a bit odd

Comment: @TimWilliams that's good to know.  I usually make a test stub but the OP's code doesn't really describe the data.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Inzina, you were right it was the c vs cell. Appreciate it!